# Preventing debugging from stopping at core library modules?

Tags: ruby, debugging

When I start debugging using:

```
ruby -rdebug file.rb
```

and place break points:

```
b path:linenumber
```

before it gets to my break point, it stops at many other points in the imported libraries.

Does any one know how to prevent that?

Note: I already know I can place `debugger` points in the code which works well, but I do not want to do that since I keep forgetting to remove them.
I'm more thinking of a solution like using an option to prevent stopping at any module under /usr/lib/ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used rdebug at all yet, but I've been having a great experience using Pry (http://pryrepl.org/). You simply stick a `binding.pry` anywhere in your code and upon execution you'll get dropped into the context of your `binding.pry`. You can then inspect variables, methods, navigate to different contexts using ls and cd, etc.

Sorry if this isn't what you were looking for!